# Npgsql low data retrieval performance with Redshift in high load scenario

Tags: .net, performance, amazon-redshift, npgsql

Application is using Npgsql 4.1.5 with .NET framework 4.6.2. This application has a **read-only access pattern** to the Redshift DB.

Application is hosted on IIS 7.5 windows server 2016 on 16 CPU cores 256 GB RAM instance in private cloud accessing AWS Redshift via VPC.

**The main concern is a high data retrieval time on the application side compared to Redshift query execution statistics.** In high load scenario 3K queries per minute. During this period 100 DB connections are used and CPU utilization is 80-100%. Each query typically retrieves 1K-50K rows with up to 10 fields.

Redshift query total execution time by percentile, sec

```
p50  | p80 |  p90 | p99
0,16 | 0,3 | 0,59 | 5,31
```

NpgSQL command execution time by percentile, sec

```
p50  | p80  | p90  | p99
1,23 | 4,92 | 9,81 | 18,13
```

NpgSQL command execution time is collected by means of logger implementation described in the [documentation](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/logging.html). The time between "Start user action" and "End user action".

Here is the connection string demonstrated the best results:

```
Minimum Pool Size=5; Maximum Pool Size=100; Connection Idle Lifetime=300; Command Timeout=0; Timeout=120; Keepalive = disabled; Max Auto Prepare = 5000; Auto Prepare Min Usages=5; Enlist=false; No Reset On Close = true
```

The typical access pattern:

```
using (DbConnection connection = NpgsqlFactory.Instance.CreateConnection())
{
    connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
    if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        connection.Open();

    using (DbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = query;
        using (var dataReader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                object[] values = new object[dataReader.FieldCount];
                for (int i = 0; i < dataReader.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                    values[i] = dataReader.GetFieldValue<object>(i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Appreciate any advice on how npgsql performance can be improved for this scenario.**

**UPD:**
After API profiling it can be confirmed that the actual cause of the delay on the API side is a network read operation.
Normally it takes 50-200ms to read query results from the socket but under the load, it spikes up to 3-15 seconds.

Read from the network stream is happening here:
https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/blob/main/src/Npgsql/NpgsqlReadBuffer.cs line 179 buffer.Underlying.Read(...)

Comment: What makes you think there's a performance problem here? The times reported by Npgsql include network waiting time, whereas on the Redshift side you're probably seeing pure query execution time. I'd recommend trying to run queries outside of .NET (e.g. from pgadmin or the command-line) to see that Npgsql isn't problematic.

Comment: Thanks for the input. That is correct for a single request: 344ms for data retrieval including 270ms pure DB execution time. This is exactly what is expected. However, with 3K queries per minute data retrieval time saturates, but DB side statistics is fine - low queue time and acceptable execution time. Our dev team is looking for a tip on what can be possibly done to improve. Is it worse to try Batching/Pipelining, multiplexing, or change the data retrieval pattern somehow, taking into account read-only access? What approach can be taken to identify the bottleneck?

Comment: It's expected for data retrieval time (i.e. networking) to generally dominate query execution times, especially in smaller queries executed on a cloud database such as Redshift. If you suspect an issue with Npgsql, I'd first try to see how the same workload behaves outside of Npgsql/.NET, as a way of isolating the issue; if you a problem only with Npgsql, that would be a good starting point for investigating on the Npgsql side.

Comment: Other than that, it's definitely recommended to batch multiple commands in a single roundtrip, wherever that's possible (regardless of Redshift).

Comment: After API profiling it can be confirmed that the actual cause of the delay on the API side is a network read operation.
Normally it takes 50-200ms to read query results from the socket but under the load, it spikes up to 3-15 seconds.

Read from the network stream is happening here:
https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/blob/main/src/Npgsql/NpgsqlReadBuffer.cs line 179 buffer.Underlying.Read(...)

@ShayRojansky is this expected from the Npgsql driver? By any chance have the Npgsql team ever noticed such a scenario?

Comment: Note that the network read time you're seeing simply tells you how long Npgsql is waiting for a response; it does not tell you the source of the slow down - slow network, slow query, or some other environmental issue. What you describe doesn't really ring any bells - I'd still try to see if the problem is reproducible when executing more or less the same workload without .NET/Npgsql (as a way of isolating the issue).

Comment: Unfortunately, AWS support and our team still now sure if this is an application issue or DB issue, or something in between. We tried to replace the npgSQL driver with the Redshift ODBC driver. Got 20% performance degradation which is kind of expected as .NET ODBC driver is just a wrapper of C++ implementation. At the same time, our application exploiting the same data retrieval pattern with ingres driver [link](https://github.com/fosslc/Ingres/tree/master/src/common/dotnet2_win) and Actian Vector DB without any issue. Apples to oranges comparison however results with Redshift are not expected